# Nucleotide sequence for STRING protein sequence

Tags: bioinformatics

I have protein sequences from STRING database:
The amino acid sequence files are like this:

> 4932.Q0010 (Saccharomyces cerevisiae)
>   MYYIMFLYNMLLIIILIFYSIVGVPIIIFNNNYYWDPDIFLFIIYYFIKFIIIFNLYLYYMINYIVYTPSGSPPGRGTYI
>   LLYNMLYSYNMFIDYVMKFITCVTYMYLMFWLLSPTPSPYYVSEVPVS

I want the corresponding nucleotide sequence for the same protein ID.

> 4932.Q0010

I tried emboss http://www.ebi.ac.uk/Tools/st/emboss_backtranseq/
But emboss is based on codon usage and backtranslate and it doesn't give me the original nucleotide sequence.

Then I tried DDBJ http://getentry.ddbj.nig.ac.jp/top-e.html
But DDBJ gives only amino acid sequences for corresponding Uniprot ID.

How do i get the original nucleotide sequence for the STRING protein sequences using STRING id or UniProt ID?

Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Comment: This should effectively clear your question http://www.uniprot.org/help/canonical_nucleotide

Comment: What is meant by canonical UniProtKB sequence?

Comment: @Raghavakrishna As it says, although most proteins derive from DNA translation, there isn't only a *single* way in which you can back translate the protein into nucleotide sequences.

Comment: @VivekRai But emboss can be used to backtranslate? http://www.ebi.ac.uk/Tools/st/emboss_backtranseq/

Answer (score 2):

Google is not a bad resource for such a question.

In this case I find that the Yeast Genome site has a button which returns the nucleotide sequence. You can select the genomic sequence for the locus or the coding (CDS) sequence.

http://www.yeastgenome.org/cgi-bin/locus.fpl?locus=Q0010

They also give a link to NCBI at the bottom of the page.  I think the reason you were having such a hard time is that UniProt extracted the protein sequence from the mitochondrial genome record.  Like many genome ORF predictions, Q0010 does not seem to have a distinct nucleotide record assigned yet.

Summary:

In general  you can do a web search for the uniprot id to start.  In many cases, like this one you will find that the nucleotide seq is only a chromosomal sequence record.   Biodatabases are a bit of a maze - there are scores of them out there, you may find that someone has clipped the nucleotide sequence of the gene out, which is helpful if there are introns!

Comment: OK for yeast,This is good.But for other organisms what is the way out?

Comment: i added a note to the post...